# Looking for an alternative for nativescript-imagepicker

Tags: nativescript

nativescript-imagepicker seems to be dependent on the telerik ui plugin.

This is a very big/heavy plugin - requiring quite a bit of resources.

It seems like image picker uses just the list-view - not sure why the built-in list-view wasn't used.

Is there an alternative to this image picker plug-in.

I'm using NS 3.3.

I know the newer version breaks up the dependency - but I'm using NS 3.3 for now and it uses nativescript-telerik-ui